# programmatically telling types of files in c++

Tags: c++, file, file-io, binaryfiles

What methods are available to programatically look at a file and tell what type of file it is, for example mp3, txt, binary, photoshop, etc.? I don't think there would be anything in the STL (except for trying to open a text file and read it in).

How does one go about trying to tell what types of files you are really dealing with? I mean I could put a .mp3 extension on a file that really isn't an mp3 file.

Comment: This might help: http://www.garykessler.net/library/magic.html

Comment: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html seems to be more accurate to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every file type has some sort of "signature," a way to look at the file and identify its structure.  In many cases, files start with a specific sequence of bytes.  For example, PDF files start with a header, that looks like this:

```
# xxd temp.pdf | head -n 1
0000000: 2550 4446 2d31 2e33 0a25 c4e5 f2e5 eba7  %PDF-1.3.%......
```

Comment: can you clarify a small bit. So I could safely check this part: 0000000: 2550 4446 2d31 2e33 0a25 c4e5 f2e5 eba7. Can you also explain in code, do I just try and open the file and check the header? Nothing in the STL right?

Comment: You just open the file, read the first few bytes, and see if they fit an established pattern.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for mention xxd, the man page is super informative

Comment: one minor clarification. Why would .txt files seem to have a different header? if I create in Sublime it has: `0000000: 6060 6063 7070` but creating in nano and vim have: `0000000: 7465 7374`

Comment: Text files shouldn't have a unique header at all.  They should contain... text.

Comment: so how does one tell for sure they are dealing with txt? if it doesn't match anything else, make an assumption? I get now why they wouldn't they aren't binary.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way around than reading the *magic number* of the file from its header, if you want to be sure. These are the bytes at the beginning. PNG files for example start with `PNG`.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote is because there's no such thing as a "magic number."

Comment: @RobertHarvey people just dont know. its a well-known term. see my edit and the wiki link

Comment: Your original answer assumed that the OP already knew what a magic number was.  I would imagine that he wouldn't have needed to ask the question if he already knew.

Comment: that is correct. I didn't. I do now. Your link was helpful. If I could have accepted 2 answers I would have.